# Ошибка "JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)" при попытке десериализации JSON

Tags: python, json, utf-8

Есть простая функция:

```
def get_nbu():
    URL = 'https://api.buh.privatbank.ua/ratenbu.php?year=1993'
    r = requests.get(URL)
    date = r.json()   #<--- json.decoder.JSONDecodeError
    return date
```

При попытке преобразовать полученный ответ в JSON получаю ошибку: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig).
Я нашел способы декодирования из файла но не могу найти решения для декодирования резултата GET-запроса (переменной). Как это решается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то в Приватбанке накосячили, т.к. в начале строки аж 3 сивмола [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark):

```
In [79]: r.text
Out[79]: '\ufeff\ufeff\ufeff[{"rate_date":"01.05.1993","rate_value":"240"},{"rate_date":"01.03.1993","rate_value":"100"}]'
```

поэтому самым простым представляется такой "костыль":

```
In [81]: r.text.lstrip('\ufeff')
Out[81]: '[{"rate_date":"01.05.1993","rate_value":"240"},{"rate_date":"01.03.1993","rate_value":"100"}]'

In [82]: import json

In [83]: items = json.loads(r.text.lstrip('\ufeff'))

In [84]: items
Out[84]:
[{'rate_date': '01.05.1993', 'rate_value': '240'},
 {'rate_date': '01.03.1993', 'rate_value': '100'}]
```

Comment: Я делаю только первые шаги. По-этому не сумел увидеть ошибку. Спасибо большое. Помогло.

Comment: @СергійСитюк, всегда пожалуйста! Именно для этого и существует данный сайт - чтобы программисты, админы и прочие айтишники помогали друг другу :)